# How to obtain a subset (of a 2-d set of points with random coordinates) having monotonically increasing ordinates

Tags: list-manipulation

If I start with a 2-d set of points:

```
 points = {{4, 4}, {6, 4}, {8, 8}, {10, 8}, {12, 8}, {14, 12}, {16, 16},  {18, 12}, {20, 16}, {22, 20}, {24, 16}, {26, 24}, {28, 24}, {30, 16}, {32, 32}, {34, 32}, {36, 24}, {38, 36}, {40, 32}, {42, 24}, {44, 40}, {46, 44}, {48, 32}, {50, 40}, {52, 48}, {54, 36}, {56, 48}, {58, 56}, {60, 32}, {62, 60}, {64, 64}, {66,  40}, {68, 64}, {70, 48}, {72, 48}, {74, 72}, {76, 72}, {78, 48}, {80,64}, {82, 80}, {84, 48}, {86, 84}, {88, 80}, {90, 48}, {92, 88}, {94, 92}, {96, 64}, {98, 84}, {100, 80}}
```

how can I build the following subset with  monotonically increasing ordinates:

> {{4, 4}, {8, 8}, {14, 12}, {16, 16}, {22, 20}, {26, 24}, {32, 
>     32}, {38, 36}, {44, 40}, {46, 44}, {52, 48}, {58, 56}, {62, 
>     60}, {64, 64}, {74, 72}, {82, 80}, {86, 84}, {92, 88}, {94, 92}}
>   ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `points` is your original list,

```
ReplaceRepeated[points,
    {bef___,x:{x1_,x2_},y:{y1_,y2_},aft___}/;x2>=y2:>{bef,x,aft}
] 
(* {{4, 4}, {8, 8}, {14, 12}, {16, 16}, {22, 20}, {26, 24}, {32, 
  32}, {38, 36}, {44, 40}, {46, 44}, {52, 48}, {58, 56}, {62, 
  60}, {64, 64}, {74, 72}, {82, 80}, {86, 84}, {92, 88}, {94, 92}} *)
```

Comment: It was the fastest of what I'd tried.  Trouble is that all the methods listed here aren't equivalent.  Try using `SeedRandom[42];
points = RandomInteger[100, {50, 2}];` and then running the different methods - they don't all give the same result.   The two methods by @rhermans give a different output on that list, and the `LongestOrderedSequence` a different result still.  Would need clarification by OP about what exactly is needed.  Is the input list always going to be already sorted?

Comment: My answers are only different if the first coordinate is not ordered. The OP has ordered and regularly spaced first coordinate.

Comment: @rhermans - it wasn't a criticism, there is some ambiguity in the OP that wasn't originally clear.  I was just pointing out that a timing test is premature since it compares apples and oranges.

Comment: It's fine, I'm just explaining the source of the difference. You could compare using `SeedRandom[42]; points = SortBy[RandomInteger[100, {50, 2}], First]`

Comment: @rhermans - If the question were "How to obtain a subset (of a pre-sorted 2-d set of points with random coordinates) having monotonically increasing ordinates", then we'd have a well-posed question and could do timing comparison (and obviously throw out my answer completely).  But that isn't how I read the question.  That's what I meant when I said a timing test is premature - the given answers do different things.

Answer (score 6):

```
LongestOrderedSequence[points, #[[2]] < #2[[2]]& ]
```

> {{4, 4}, {8, 8}, {14, 12}, {16, 16}, {22, 20}, {26, 24}, {32, 
>     32}, {38, 36}, {44, 40}, {46, 44}, {52, 48}, {58, 56}, {62, 
>     60}, {64, 64}, {74, 72}, {82, 80}, {86, 84}, {92, 88}, {94, 92}}

In, general, if input list is not already sorted by the first column:

```
LongestOrderedSequence[points, And @@ Thread @ Less @ ## & ]
```

> same result

Alternatively, we get the same result using a combination of `FixedPoint` and `Split`, or a combination of rhermans's and Bill's methods:

```
FixedPoint[First /@ Split[#, #[[1]] >= #2[[1]] || #[[2]] >= #2[[2]] &] &, points]
DeleteDuplicates @ FoldList[If[#2[[2]] > #[[2]], #2, #] &, points]
```

For `points` in OP all the methods posted so far are faster than `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
LongestOrderedSequence[points , #[[2]] < #2[[2]] & ] ; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00021

```
FixedPoint[First /@ Split[#,  #[[2]] >= #2[[2]] &] &, points] ; // RepeatedTiming// First
```

> 0.00013

```
DeleteDuplicates @ FoldList[ First[MaximalBy[Last][{#1, #2}]] &, points]; //
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0024

```
  Union[points, SameTest -> (Last@#1 <= Last@#2 &)] ; //  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00019

```
 (p = {0, 0};
 Map[If[p[[1]] < #[[1]] && p[[2]] < #[[2]], p = #, fail] &,  points] /. 
  fail -> Sequence[]); //  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00018

```
 DeleteDuplicates@FoldList[If[#2[[2]] > #[[2]], #2, #] &, points]  ; //
```

RepeatedTiming // First

> 0.000082

```
ReplaceRepeated[points,
        {bef___, x : {x1_, x2_}, y : {y1_, y2_}, aft___} /; 
      x2 >= y2 :> {bef, x, aft}
    ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00056

For general input, the `LongestOrderedSequence` and other methods do not produce the same results. `LongestOrderedSequence` does produce the longest monotone  sequence which does not necessarily include the first pair in the input list. The monotone sequence produced by other methods starts with the first pair but the sequence produced is not necessarily  the longest possible.

**Timings:**

```
f1 = LongestOrderedSequence[# , #[[2]] < #2[[2]] & ] &;
f2 = FixedPoint[First /@ Split[#, #[[2]] >= #2[[2]] &] &, #] & ;
f3 = DeleteDuplicates @ FoldList[If[#2[[2]] > #[[2]], #2, #] &, #] &;
f4 = (p = {0, 0}; Map[If[ p[[2]] < #[[2]], p = #, fail] &, #] /. fail -> Sequence[]) &;
f5 = DeleteDuplicates @ FoldList[First[MaximalBy[Last][{#1, #2}]] &, #] &;
f6 = Union[#, SameTest -> (Last@#1 <= Last@#2 &)] &;
f7 = ReplaceRepeated[# , {bef___, x : {x1_, x2_}, y : {y1_, y2_}, aft___} /; 
      x2 >= y2 :> {bef, x, aft}] &;
```

The function `f4` is from Bill's answer, `f5` and `f6` are from rhermans' answer, and `f7` from Jason B.'s.

```
SeedRandom[1]
pnts = SortBy[RandomInteger[100, {10000, 2}], First]; 
timings = Table[0, 7];
results = Table[0, 7];
functions = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7};
labels = {"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7"} ;

timings = Table[First[RepeatedTiming[results[[i]] = functions[[i]]@pnts;]], {i, 7}];

Prepend[SortBy[Transpose[{labels, timings, Length /@ results, First /@ results}], 
  #[[2]] &], {"f", "timing", "Length@f@pnts", "First@f@pnts" }] /.
    x_Real :> NumberForm[x, {2, 4}] // 
      Grid[#, Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {Right, Center} ] &
```

> $\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
> \hline
>  f & \text{timing} & \text{Length@f@pnts} & \text{First@f@pnts} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f3} & 0.0038 & 57 & \{0,3\} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f6} & 0.0130 & 57 & \{0,3\} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f4} & 0.0210 & 57 & \{0,3\} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f1} & 0.1100 & 101 & \{3,0\} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f2} & 0.3500 & 57 & \{0,3\} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f5} & 0.5400 & 57 & \{0,3\} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f7} & 24.0000 & 57 & \{0,3\} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

All methods except `LongestOrderedSequence` give the same output:

```
Equal @@ Rest[results]
```

> True

Comment: Point taken that `ReplaceRepeated` is much slower under these conditions (the list being already sorted, and with *many* duplicate values).

Answer (score 4):

```
benchmark = {{4, 4}, {8, 8}, {14, 12}, {16, 16}, {22, 20}, {26, 
   24}, {32, 32}, {38, 36}, {44, 40}, {46, 44}, {52, 48}, {58, 
   56}, {62, 60}, {64, 64}, {74, 72}, {82, 80}, {86, 84}, {92, 
   88}, {94, 92}}
```

### f5

Not very good, but my first thought. End up been the second slowest in @kglr's test.

```
DeleteDuplicates@FoldList[
  First[MaximalBy[Last][{#1, #2}]] &,
  points
  ] == benchmark

(* True *)
```

### f6

I like the simplicity if this one, and end up been the second fastest in @kglr's test.

```
Union[points, SameTest -> (Last@#1 <= Last@#2 &)] == benchmark

(* True *)
```

Comment: I think `DeleteDuplicates[points, Last@#1 >= Last@#2 &]` is better, `Union[points,SameTest->...]` isn't always correct.

Comment: @chyanog got any examples of it failing?

Comment: `points=RandomInteger[100,{50,2}];
res1=DeleteDuplicates@FoldList[First[MaximalBy[Last][{#1,#2}]]&,points];
res2=DeleteDuplicates[points,Last@#1>=Last@#2&];
res3=Union[points,SameTest->(Last@#1<=Last@#2&)];
{res1==res2,res1==res3}`

Comment: @chyanog this was discussed already in other comments. My answers are only different if the first coordinate is not ordered. The OP has ordered and regularly spaced first coordinate.

Answer (score 3):

Using more basic functions, test the each pair against the last success and either accept or leave a marker to reject. When done delete the markers.

```
p = {0, 0};
Map[If[p[[1]] < #[[1]] && p[[2]] < #[[2]], p = #, fail]&, points]/.fail->Sequence[]

(*{{4, 4}, {8, 8}, {14, 12}, {16, 16}, {22, 20}, {26, 24}, {32, 32}, {38, 36}, {44, 40},
   {46, 44}, {52, 48}, {58, 56}, {62, 60}, {64, 64}, {74, 72}, {82, 80}, {86, 84},
   {92, 88}, {94, 92}}*)
```

or

```
p = {0, 0};
DeleteCases[Map[If[p[[1]] < #[[1]] && p[[2]] < #[[2]], p = #, fail]&, points], fail]
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you all for your answers! This is a question for which I couldn't find a straight answer anywhere.  Now, all these approaches are located nicely in one place for everyone's benefit.

Comment: I suggest that you take each of the approaches, study the functions used and how they are put together and see if you can understand how the approach works. When you have done that then see if you could imagine using or modifying that method for other problems that you might have in the future. That may provide you with the most learning for your future use of Mathematica. If you can learn a few of the basic functions and how to apply those then that may help you solve lots of different kinds of problems.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation Bill.  I spend considerable time comparing methods and approaches because that's when the real learning occurs.